# How to limit the access of a local windows user to only a specific folder?

Tags: windows, ssh, permissions, sftp, acl

I've set up an OpenSSH SFTP connection with the help of documentation and WinSCP and want a colleague to be able to upload files to my computer using this SFTP connection.

- I've created a new local user on my machine and when I test the connection, I'm able to view all folders, root directory, etc., but am unable to access any other folders except the one which I created (which is good), however I need to limit the permissions so the new user can only view the folder they're to upload the file to.
- I've checked the permissions on via *Properties* > *Permissions* > *Security* to see the users/groups that have access and have removed the new user from the `users` group
- The new user doesn't appear to have access to any folder, but when I connect using [WinSCP] SFTP, I'm still able to see all folders; however, when I click a folder, I don't have access to it and receive an error.

How can I restrict the new user to only have access to view a single folder, as well as force the SFTP connection to open to that folder upon connecting?

Comment: This will need to be double-checked, but the easiest way would be to **(1)** Create a Windows user with no user-profile via `net user add`; **(2)** Create a non-default group for that specific user; **(3)** Ensure the new user is removed from all other groups; **(4)** Add that user to the ACL for the folder you want the user to access, providing the user only _Files Only_ access (it may need to _This Folder and Files_) with _Write Only_ privs. Also see [`icacls /?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)

Comment: @JW0914 not sure what you mean by "create a non default group"? I've done all the other steps but the same problem still remains, the user has view access on all folders.

Comment: Create a new group that doesn't exist by default, adding the new user to it _(this isn't required, but I find it helpful when adding users without a user profile)_. Does `net user <username>` return any `Group memberships`? You may have to explicitly _Deny_ the new user access to `C:`, selecting _This folder, subfolders, and files_. I've never done so before, so you may have to play with this a little to find the right combination, as doing so to `C:` may block that user's access to the folder you want access to; if so, you may need to use the _Advanced Permissions_ section if using the GUI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restrict users to sftp in OpenSSH on Windows Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/1549527/how-do-i-restrict-users-to-sftp-in-openssh-on-windows-server)

Answer (score 0):

below should help

> ```
> > Match User User1 ChrootDirectory E:\user1folder Match Group
> > administrators AuthorizedKeysFile
> > __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys X11Forwarding no AllowTcpForwarding no ForceCommand internal-sftp Match User
> > Administrator X11Forwarding no AllowTcpForwarding no ForceCommand
> > internal-sftp
> ```