# When to use sftp-server with -d option in conjunction with ChrootDirectory?

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, chroot-jail

The [docs](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp-server) for `sftp-server` state that the `-d` option *is useful in conjunction with the sshd_config ChrootDirectory option*. I've also seen some [answers](https://superuser.com/a/1550010/1256087) on the internet where in order to restrict users to a specific folder you should combine the `-d` option with `ChrootDirectory`, like the docs mention.

However, when testing (server and client both running windows 10) I found that `ChrootDirectory` alone was enough and the user could never access parent folders:

```ruby
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

AllowUsers test
ForceCommand internal-sftp
ChrootDirectory "E:\Some\Path\To\Some\Folder"
```

So my question is, when should the `-d` option be used and when is only `ChrootDirectory` enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might chroot to a shared `/some/directory`, where each user has its own subdirectory.

You will then want to set `-d` to `/%u`. That way each user starts in his/hers directory, but can access the others.